# how to integrate libsynthesis in ios app syncML

Tags: ios, iphone, syncml, funambol

I am attempting to implement `sync ML` in my ios app for integrating contacts with a sync `ML server`.

I have 2 libraries , `funambol` and `lib synthesis` .

`Funambol` has its own app but there were a lot of errors integrating it so i moved to `lib synthesis` .

The problem is it is building in `iOS 5` but not in `iOS 6` .

I am getting a lot of lexical preprocessor issues while doing so. I have checked all the header paths, but am getting no direction to move ahead.

Comment: Post the errors you are receiving!!

Comment: I am recieving lexical preprocessor issues in iOS 6 like target_options.h file not found

Comment: Post them here mate!! We cannot help unless we see the exact errors!!